# Slash commands not listing in console (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, command, slash

I recently have been using discord.js to make slash commands but made a typo. Instead of making it say /help, I made it say /hlep. I tried to find its its id by using `console.log(client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.get())`, but it just said `Promise { <pending> }` in console and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can't be use without seeing complete code but try client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.get().then(result => console.log(result))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.get()` is [asynchronous](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/how-to-write-asynchronous-code/), it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of an object.

From MDN:

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason.

> A pending promise can either be fulfilled with a value or rejected with a reason (error).

Either use the `.then` function, to run code when the Promise fulfils:

```js
client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.get().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // You may also put other code here to be run when it is fulfilled.
});
```

... or use it in an asynchronous function like so:

```js
let result = await client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.get();
console.log(result);
```